# Connecting my phone to my computer?

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, drivers, android-studio

This is my first question on `superuser`, and I would really appreciate your help on this issue:

**The problem:** My device isn't getting detected in android studio

**The solution:** Install the correct usb drivers

**The problem that arises to the solution:** I am not able to...and here are the details:

I have recently system wiped my computer due to slowness. This brings me back to the tedious task of setting up my computer for android studio. I have tried **everything** to get  the usb drivers to work in android studio, but for some reason, I can't update my usb driver:
[image]

Now, here is the annoying screen that always pops up when trying to update my usb driver:

[image]

My usb driver **is installed:**

[image]

This is pretty pathetic. I have tried everything. **I even tried to go into my computers bios and disable Intel xHCI.** I remember when I first started android, I had this same problem, and the solution was to do something in the computer's bios, but the problem still persists.

By the way, I have done lots of research on this topic, and this is a code 28, which means it doesn't have the correct drivers:

[image]

I have been on this for 3 hours now (3 HOURS!) and would really appreciate **any** help. How can I get my phone recognized on my windows 8 laptop? I have done it before, so I know my phone is compatible.

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Comment: Lies. LIES I TELL YOU!!  +1 upvote for making me laugh.

Comment: @WesSayeed My thoughts exactly! "They must be lying, since I have done it before! How could they!" But, in all seriousness, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Now I'm not trying to insult your intelligence here. I'm just curious... you did actually try to install this driver via Device Manager, correct?  You didn't just copy it to the android SDK folder right?

Comment: @WesSayeed Yes. I went to device manager->Update Driver Software->Browse my Computer Manually->MESSAGE: Unable to install. I did nothing with the SDK folder except for browse for it, which was in the following path: `C:\Users\Ruchir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`.

Comment: @WesSayeed Is that what you mean...or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

While I've never had this problem these are the steps I would take if I were you:

1. Google (your phone name) + "driver" to make sure there is no special driver that you do not have installed.
2. Look in your phone settings to make sure you do not have some PC connection option unticked.
3. Try uninstalling and reinstalling all drivers to do with the connection of your android phone.

[This guide might be helpful.](http://www.howtogeek.com/195607/how-to-get-your-android-device-to-show-up-in-file-explorer-if-it-isnt/)

Comment: Also after reading the comment on the main question instead of trying manually install the driver try the automatic update option instead. Just a thought.

Comment: Well, the phone is showing up in file explorer, and **is** getting recognized by my computer. But, when I run android studio, it is not getting recognized. This means there is a problem with the device drivers. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Is android studio recognizing other devices? If no, then it may be a problem with android studio. And I would refer you to my first suggestion. Have you checked if there is a special driver for your phone that you might not have installed? If I may ask what is the model of phone that you have?

Comment: I have done this entire process before I system wiped my computer. Before, it would work without a need to install anything special. I also remember that last time, I did something in my system bios...

Comment: If it was something in your system bios I'm thinking maybe it was the hardware virtualization option (VT-x). Try this link                              http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/                                                                  This will allow you to enable hardware virtualization. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Alright, I am trying it now. In the mean time, what does Intel xHCI do? I disabled it, should I reenable it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32027/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-law10).

Comment: Intel xHCI just has to do with usb 3.0 ports as I understand it and it should not affect this situation in any way. However, sometimes things that should not affect things do so it would not hurt to try it both ways just to make sure it is not an issue.

Comment: Should I disable the visualization technology option? It is enabled right now. Is that even the same thing as the VT-x option?

Comment: Yes it is the same and my suggestion was to enable it but if it is already enabled you can always try disabling it to see if it works though I'm not sure why that would make a difference but it's worth a shot. The only two options that would make sense changing in your BIOS would be the virtualization and/or xHCI options. Try enabling and disabling both of these. If this doesn't work I would say it is a driver issue and not something in your BIOS.

Comment: Which ones? Should I enable one and disable the other? Or should I disable both?

Answer (score -1):

First make sure that you have virtualization on in the bios.

Next, make sure you have done what I have done in my question.

What I forgot to do was install the `android_winusb` file in the usb_driver folder. The path should be `sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`. In my case, `C:\Users\Ruchir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

After doing that, go **back** to device manager and go to the install as path. At the bottom of that should be another option:

Let me pick from a list of devices on my computer

Select your android phone, it shouldn't have a yellow explamation point over it any more. After that, select `composite ADB Interface`. THATS IT.

Windows made this whole process so long. I spent 7 and a half hours on it today!